# add to cart disabled after installing check delivery netsolutions from magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have installed Check availability by zip/postal code from magento connect so that it checks product availability using pincode.

reference :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/check-availability-by-zip-postal-code.html

It is working fine but my add to cart button in all my product page is disabled.

I guess **checkdelivery.xml** is conflicting. please guide me how to enable add to cart button.